# Reinstalling Visual Studio 2017 Community after 30-day trial expired

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Like many others, I installed VS 2017 Community and did not register it so the 30-day trial period expired.  Many solutions suggested were to sign in with a Microsoft Account.  On the "sign in to your account" screen no keystrokes could be accepted so I could not enter an account.  Uninstalling the entire package and reinstalling produced the same license expired notification and unresponsive account sign-in screen.  Would like guidance as to reinstalling VS 2017 Community so it does not know about previous installs so I can start over without buying a new computer.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe you can go back to a restore point before the vs 2017 installation.

Comment: Try the visual studio uninstaller.  https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller

Answer (score 0):

For those who experience this problem: delete `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Licenses\5C505A59-E312-4B89-9508-E162F8150517` branch.

Comment: removing and restarting does not help here. Perhaps another branch?